# Linux daemon vs foreground application

Tags: linux, console, daemon

What are the advantages of ["daemonizing"](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/daemon.3.html) a server application over running the program in console mode?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Having it run as a daemon means you can

- log out without loosing the service (which saves some resources)
- do not risk loosing the service from an accidental ctrl-c
- does not offer a minor security risk from someone accessing the terminal, hitting ctrl-c and taking your session

Essentially all 'real' services that are running 'in production' (as opposed to debug mode) run that way.

Answer (score 6):

I think it is preventing from accidentally closing an app and you have one more terminal free.
But I personally don't see big difference between "screen" program and "daemonizing"

Comment: "screen" does the "daemonizing" for you so ... yeah, although you can still be brutal in your screen session, and having screen die or be killed would have an adverse effect... anyway, the question is about the [normal] console, and this does bring up a handy tool so +1.

Comment: There is a HUGE difference: with `screen`, you are still attached to a tty!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood but you can change terminals with screen. Unless the terminal is something different than tty.

Answer (score 6):

The main point would be to detach the process from the terminal so that the process does not terminate when the user logs out from the terminal. If you run a program in console mode, it will terminate when you log out, because this is the default behavior for a process when it receives a SIGHUP signal.

Note that there is more to writing a daemon than just calling daemon(3). See [How to write a unix daemon](http://cjh.polyplex.org/software/daemon.pdf) for more information.